# Welfare economics and Equity

Tags: microeconomics

What would be the advantages of an equitable social security system in Australia?
I am trying to explain this using Pareto efficiency and the efficiency/equity tradeoff.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is too vague to address, what do you even consider an equitable social security system? Equitable in what sense? In terms of utility, consumption, income? Also what do you consider a benefit? Welfare economics is science as such it is agnostic about what is beneficial and what isn’t